# Project Server Login Issue

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, project-server, project-server-2007

I have migrated Project server from one server to another.

I am able to see all the content that was present in the old server by appending

> _layouts/user.aspx

or whatever I want to see.

However I am unable to see the Project server home page. As we know Project Server has its own security model.

Can anybody throw light on this problem and help with a solution?

Comment: What steps did you take to migrate the server from one box to another? Hard to give input if we don't know what you did.

Comment: How did you perform the migration? What error/message do you get when you try to connect to project server/PWA?

Comment: For Backup C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\BIN>stsadm.exe -o backup -url YYYYYYY/pwa -filename c:\ stsbackup\backup.dat -overwrite For Restore on new Server C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\BIN>stsa dm.exe -o restore -url XXXXXXXX:XXXX/XXXXX -filename C:\stsbackup

Comment: I also tried these: http://blogs.msdn.com/brismith/archive/2009/06/22/project-server-2007-migration-from-one-domain-to-another.aspx




http://proj2007.blogspot.com/2007/10/migrate-project-server-2007-from-one.html

Comment: Error Message: The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.

Comment: You moved across machines but not domains, right? What are you using for authentication, Active Directory?

Comment: Yes Curtisk, I have moved it to new server in same domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be some webpart on the homepage is not accessible to everyone. Have you tried to log into the site using the credentials of the service account the site's App pool is running under?